# How can I fix this iFile to output .txt into my console?

Tags: c++, output

This is a function I made in C++ to read account data from *.txt files* but my program closes when I open it.

```
static void ReadData() {
    string *line[21];
    ifstream myfile2("Userinfo1.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        if (myfile2.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(myfile2, *line[i]))
            {
                cout << *line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    myfile2.close();
    ifstream myfile("Userinfo2.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(myfile, *line[i]))
            {
                cout << *line << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Thanks In advance for any help!

Comment: `while (getline(myfile2, *line[i]))` will read the full file, so sticking that inside of a loop almost definitely isn't what you want. What is in your files? What is this code supposed to do? Do the files open correctly? Is anything output? Does your program exit with an error or exit normally?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Please read through the following guide which will help you to frame your questions with enough context that you are more likely to get the answers you are looking for. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Best of luck.

Comment: I'm trying to read 22 lines of my text file. I've limited all the files to only accept 22 lines of information and I wanted to keep each line of those text files stored in a reference in an array. I'm not too sure if it's the best way to go about it, but I want to output all 22 lines of code to the console. When I run the method it just closes without running any code after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you try to read 21 lines of file and print it. So I quickly impove your code. Firstly, there is no need to make an array of string. If you want to save this lines you could use `std::vector<std::string>`. Then you shouldn't check that file is open every time. And finally if you want to read all lines from file you just should check end of file. Hope I can help you.

```
std::string line;
ifstream myfile2("Userinfo1.txt");
if (myfile2.is_open()) {
    while (!myfile2.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile2, line);
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
myfile2.close();
```

Comment: Yes that's a good point. I wanted to limit the amount of lines read to 21 because I wanted to allocate only 22 lines of information to the text file. In other methods I used it to keep the pattern and be able to read through names, Id's, and people's account numbers sequentially. I'll check if this fixes my problem and I'll get right back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you very much. i wanted a way to save the locations of names and such and use those same positions as references for account numbers but if everything is in order, I don't think I'll need to do that. Thanks for the help!